# Real time data Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

First of all, I am very new to Angular and I am struggling to get this right.
I have made an app that I want to get real time data from a web server that is posting JSON data from an mssql server.

I have managed to retrive data like so

```
export class AppComponent {


posts:string;

  constructor(http: Http) {
  http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')

    .map(res => res.json())

    .subscribe(data => this.posts = data);
}
}
```

and then just insert it to my html document like this `<h1>{{data.id}}</h1>`

But when my web server updates the JSON, the html does not update at all. 
I understand that I am missing something essential , like observable and I would be grateful if someone can push me in the right direction.

Comment: If you are asking about `push` or `sockets`, which you seem to imply,  you need to either look at services like `socket.io`, `pusher`, `strongloop`, `firebase`, `horizon` etc.  or (as I see answers below )  - do polling which is so 2010 ;)  but it will also handle this issue, just less graceful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to continuously ask the server for the latest data, you'll need to call the server at an interval:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class AppComponent {

  posts:string;

  ngOnInit() {
     this.posts = Observable
         .interval(1000) // call once per second
         .startWith(0)
         .switchMap(() => 
             this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
                 .map((res: Response) => res.json());
         })
         // example how to get just the first result
         .map(posts => posts[0]);
 }
```

Then in template use async pipe:

```
<pre>{{ (posts | async) | json }}</pre>
```

Comment: This works great but now I [object, Object]. Can I extract an object from an array? Or something?

Comment: Strange, it displays fine for me. Did you include the | json pipe in the template as well as the res.json() to transform the response? If you can, create a plunkr to reproduce

Comment: Yes! When I did I got every json object. Any way to select only one or two object?

Comment: Which one do you want to get? You get an array from the backend you just need to filter it for the data you want

Comment: If for example you want the first post, you can attach another map after the switchMap: .map(posts => posts[0])

Comment: First of all , thanks for being so helpfull. I really really appreciate it! Second when I do that I get the whole Json object. Not a specific data in that JSON object.

Comment: Your welcome, glad to help! I edited my answer with the map that only gets the first result. Did you try it like that?

Answer (score 1):

You should move that http call into a service eventually, but for learning purposes you can move it into a method that is called by ngOnInit when the component initializes. Since you want to get data continuously, use an interval on the observable.

This might not be the perfect/exact code you can copy/paste, but it should give you some ideas.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
//import Angular's Http or custom Http

//(Your decorators/class declaration here)

  posts$: Observable<yourType[]>

  constructor(http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit(){
      this.getData();
  }

  getData(): void {
      this.posts$ = Observable.interval(1000)
                              .startsWith(0)
                              .switchMap(() => 
          this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
                   .map(res => res.json());
          )
  }
```

Then use the async pipe and *ngFor loop in your template:

```
  <div *ngFor="let post of (posts$ | async)">
     <h1>{{post?.id}}</h1>
  </div>
```